# WSO2 Governance and Certificates

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Folks,
does anyone know if the WSO Governance software (version 4) supports SHA-2 certificates?  If so, is there anything different to install vs SHA-1 certs?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use very old greg version? AFAIK SHA-2 certificates are supported in newer Greg versions. e.g. 4.6.0, 5.0.0, etc...

Comment: NO particular reason -- we did the install for the 4.5.3 version and never had a need to do any upgrades.    We may NOW need to do upgrades to the system (not sure yet), but if we don't, does the 4.5.3 support SHA-2?  If so, is there anything different to add those to the system?

Comment: There are new versions available for G-Reg such as G-Reg 5.1.0, Other than that WSO2 is working on G-Reg 5.2.0 release these days. It will be better to use the latest version.
https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/releases

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 pack with me at the moment. I believe, you will be able to figure it out as follows.

All WSO2 products has tomcat embedded in them. Thats how the management console is presented. If you do a find for 'tomcat', you will find a jar in repository/components/plugins folder. I am not sure whether it is the embedded tomcat jar or the normal one (there is a difference in those two). As far as I know, earlier days it was the embedded tomcat jar and then WSO2 started using the normal one.

After you find the version of that jar (for example Governance Registry 4.6.0 uses tomcat 7.0.34), you should be able to do a search and find out whether that version of tomcat supports SHA2 or not.